# How to reply when a company rejected your Skype interview request?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, internship

So I got an e-mail from a company on a different state. Although it's still possible for me to travel there with a flight, it's not something that I could easily afford, especially for a first round interview. So I sent a reply to the company asking if it's possible to schedule a Skype Interview, which he rejected.

He didn't seem pleased with what I've asked so he replied with a very short message saying that he unfortunately doesn't accept Skype interviews. I'm not sure how I should reply to this? Is it polite to ask that in the first place?

Comment: If a company requires an on-site interview from non-local applicants, usually they will pay for your travel expenses.

Comment: If a company requires an on-site interview, and they are talking to non-local applicants, they are generally EXPECTED to pay travel expenses, even for entry-level hires.  If you are non-local for them, it is ALWAYS appropriate for you to ask them if they are paying travel expenses.  If they say "No", you thank them politely, wish them well, and never talk to them again.

Comment: I would say this depends on culture and the job at hand. If you are keen on finding a job there, but the company is not especially keen on getting someone non-local you may have to invest ...

Comment: I don't think that's the case for the company I've applied for, since he's not offering anything when I told him that I'll be out of the states. How long do you think is appropriate before I give him a reply? I'm thinking to ask if I can reschedule the interview with him and maybe arrange to fly there? I'm questioning myself it it would be worth it though since I might potentially not get the job

Comment: If the company wants you to fly across the country for a round one interview and wont even compensate you for it, I think that the potential for not getting the job is in your best interest. This is the reddest red flag I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you for your time

For non-Junior roles some companies do cover travel expenses. In my experience (UK) juniors are usually not worth the hassle. See [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/23293/9549) on the subject.

That said, your contact would've let you know if that were the case, so this one's probably a loss. I'm assuming you explicitly stated that you can't attend in-person due to cost - if not, it's a good idea to ask about that instead (see linked question and answers).

Comment: I didn't state my reason yet. I just told him that I'm living out of the states and simply ask if it's possible to schedule a Skype interview. I'm pretty sure that the company won't cover my travel expenses. My only problem is that I'm  currently evacuating from the hurricane and have make plans for the week already and it's impossible for me to travel there during this time. Do you think it would be appropriate to ask if I can re-schedule the interview? I don't know for sure if I can fly there though.

Comment: @TashaN. I think it would be appropriate to ask to reschedule, while mentioning the above. This might make him feel like a piece of excrement to refuse, and might even make him rethink about the Skype policy - but that's a big _might_. I think it's likely that they'll let you reschedule - that's a hell of an extenuating circumstance! Speaking of, I hope you and your family are safe.

Comment: I'll try to explain the whole situation to him, hopefully he'll respond positively. How long do you think I should wait before giving him a reply? I just want to make sure that I will be able to fly there if he agrees to reschedule. Thank you rath! We hope everyone in the area of the hurricane would be safe too.

Comment: @TashaN. As soon as convenient really, the fact that you didn't play the hurricane card in your initial interaction speaks well of your character. The tone of your previous comment, ie. not trying to evoke pity but explaining the situation, is what you want to aim for. Just remember he's still entitled to refuse to accommodate your request.